# esri.dijit.popup custom layout

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I'm looking for a way to customize the layout of popup.
What is asket to me is to change the defined labels of navigation inserting a custom string and move and change the icons to navigate

the first change is something like this:
change the header title
"(1 of 2])"
to
"element 1 of 2"

the second change is to move the navigation tools from the header to the footer and to use labels instead of images (something like previous/next)

Is that possible or do i need to implement a own popuptemplate?
thanks

Comment:  
This question appears to be abandoned because it has not attracted any activity, and its asker has not logged into this site, for 14 months. Consequently, I am voting to close it. It can always be re-opened in the future. 